# How is the following limit is true?

Tags: limits, fourier-transform, dirac-delta

$
{(1)\space \displaystyle \lim _{a\to 0}{\frac {\sin \left({\frac {\pi x}{a}}\right)}{\pi x}}=\lim _{a\to 0}{\frac {1}{a}}\operatorname {sinc} \left({\frac {x}{a}}\right)=\delta (x).}
$
How is that true, giving that the delta is defined that way $(2)\space \delta (x)={\begin{cases}+\infty ,&x=0\\0,&x\neq 0\end{cases}}.$
And why Fourier Transform in our course we use the definition number (2) even though the definition (1) align better with Fourier Transform of cosine and sine.

Comment: I put the numbers before the definitions mentioned above.

Comment: If the limit is when $\;a\to0\;$ then the leftmost limit doesn't even exist...shouldn't it perhaps be the limit when $\;x\to0\;$ ?

Comment: It seems like (2) is not a definition. At heart, $\delta$ is not a function, it is a “functional,” as in functional analysis. The best definition of $\delta$ is really simple: $\langle\delta ,f\rangle=f(0).$ You can show that it is the limit of functionals related to the functions in (1), or a lot of other limits of functions as functionals.

Comment: @DonAntonio i got that from Wikipedia.https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sinc_function#Relationship_to_the_Dirac_delta_distribution

Comment: @DonAntonio the limit doesn’t exist as a function, but $\delta$ is not a function, either. The limit is as functionals.

Comment: As far as I know, the sinc function is defined as $\;sin x:=\frac{\sin x}x\;$ . Maybe they multiply things by $\;\pi\;$ ...

Comment: @ThomasAndrews As defined in the Wiki page, it is the weak limit (in the weak topology)...Ok. Anyway, I never saw that "definition" of the Dirac Function. not in Harmonic Analysis, not in Partial Differential Equations...But I guess it's fine defining it in that particular special case.

Comment: Mr. @ThomasAndrews thank you i don't know what is functional but i think you have put me in the right track to understand this.

Comment: I wouldn’t define it that way, myself, but one doesn’t need it as a definition to use it as a definition. You just need to know the (weak) convergence to another definition of $\delta,$ and what weak convergence let’s you do.  @DonAntonio

Comment: A similar but more typical limit definition would be to define $$f(x)=\begin{cases}1&-1<x<1\\0&\text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$ and get  $$\delta=\lim_{a\to\infty} af(2ax)$$ It is much easier to show this (functional) limit.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews: My problem with this hole question is when I try to get the Fourier Transform of $e^{ix}$ the limit denoted by (1) in my question came to me, but in the course we use the definition that you just mentioned in the last comment and that confuses me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The $\delta$ distribution is *not* defined the way you write. A more correct definition is
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \delta(x) \, f(x) \, dx = f(0),$$
where $f$ is a "nice" function.

To show that $\frac{\sin \frac{\pi x}{a}}{\pi x} \to \delta(x)$ we need to show that
$$
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\sin \frac{\pi x}{a}}{\pi x} \, f(x) \, dx
\to f(0) 
$$
when $a\to 0$ and $f$ is a "nice" function.

And, using the substitution $y=\frac{\pi x}{a},$ we have
$$
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\sin \frac{\pi x}{a}}{\pi x} \, f(x) \, dx
= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\sin y}{ay} \, f(\frac{ay}{\pi}) \, \frac{a\,dy}{\pi}
= \frac{1}{\pi} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\sin y}{y} \, f(\frac{ay}{\pi}) \, dy
\to \frac{1}{\pi} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\sin y}{y} \, f(0) \, dy
\\
= \frac{1}{\pi} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\sin y}{y} \, dy \, f(0)
= f(0)
$$
since $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\sin y}{y}=\pi.$

Comment: Ok thank you that was helpful but to be sure I got it right, here is what I understand "delta is not specific function and could be many functions" is that right and if that right when to chose one function over the other? like what is the delta we should use in Fourier Transform? I think it should be the one including sinc(x) not the rectangle that gets narrower as when I try to get Fourier Transform of sin(x) and cos(x) that one including sinc(x) is the one to appear.

Comment: @Mohamedsaad. Delta is not a function; it's a distribution. There are however many sequences of functions that converge to delta. If you want to treat delta as the limit of a sequence of functions, you should choose a sequence that is appropriate for the case.